# Weights in eigenface approach

Tags: machine-learning, pca, eigenvector

1) In [eigenface](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenface) approach the eigenfaces is a combination of elements from different faces. What are these elements?

2) The output face is an image composed of different eigenfaces with different weights. What does the weights of eigenfaces exactly mean? I know that the weight is percentage of eigenfacein the image, but what does it mean exactly, is mean the number of selected pixels?

Answer (score 0):

Please study about PCA to understand what is the physical meaning of eigenfaces, when PCA is applied to an image. The answer lies in the understanding of eigenvectors and eigenvalues associated with PCA.

Answer (score 0):

- EigenFaces is based on Principal Component Analysis
- Principal Component Analysis does dimensionality reduction and finds unique features in the training images and removes the similar features from the face images
- By getting unique features our recognition task gets simpler
- By using PCA you calculate the eigenvectors for your face image data
- From these eigenvectors you calculate EigenFace of every training subject or you can say calculating EigenFace for every class in your data
- So if you have 9 classes then the number of EigenFaces will be 9
- The weight usually means how important something is
- In EigenFaces weight of a particular EigenFace is a vector which just tells you how important that particular EigenFace is in contributing the MeanFace
- Now if you have 9 EigenFaces then for every EigenFace you will get exactly one Weight vector which will be of N dimension where N is number of eigenvectors
- So every element out N elements in one weight vector will tell you how important that particular eigenvector is for that corresponding EigenFace
- The facial Recognition in EigenFaces is done by comparing the weights of training images and testing images with some kind of distance function
- You can refer this github link: https://github.com/jayshah19949596/Computer-Vision-Course-Assignments/blob/master/EigenFaces/EigenFaces.ipynb
- The code on the above link is a good documented code so If you know the basics you will understand the code